# Duplicate/Copy a whole function in PyCharm

Tags: python, function, pycharm, copy

is there a comfortable way to copy/duplicate a whole function in PyCharm? Of course, I can mark the whole code in the editor and copy&paste it. But is there a way to mark only the name of the function anywhere and make a copy of it?
I tried to visualize it: I want to make a copy of the function breadthmergeleft and insert it in the CheckGroupSetting.py-file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUZzA.png)

With kind regards

I tried to google "duplicate/copy" a whole function in PyCharm but I did not find what described above.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to use this function in multiple places create a class with the "breadthmergeleft" function then import the class and use the function or convert it to a package.

it's not a good practice to duplicate a code. always remember the "DRY" rule.

I hope this answer helps you

Comment: Well, I'm uses to program in a proprietary language where functions can easily been copy&pasted but, yes, of course you are right, this induces to make messy code.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of operation we use 'modules', create a python file
*CheckGroupSetting.py* and insert a function into this file.
[enter image description here][1]

```
C:\Users\hacker\PycharmProjects\pythonProject4>ls
CheckGroupSetting.py  main.py
```

here we have the 'main.py' this file from which we will run our code and another file is module from which we will import function, class and etc.

**CheckGroupSetting.py**

```
def add_two_variable(x, y):
    return x + y
```

**main.py**

```
from CheckGroupSetting import add_two_variable

print(add_two_variable(1, 2))
```

it is also important to cover the topic

> if '__name__' == '__main__'

if you want to understand it completely

Answer (score 0):

You can collapse the function by clicking the down arrow beside the line number then just copy the one line to copy the entire collapsed section.